# Cassandra is configured to lose 10 seconds of data by default?

Tags: cassandra, data-integrity, scylla, data-loss, durability

As the data in the Commitlog is flushed to the disk periodically after every 10 seconds by default (controlled by `commitlog_sync_period_in_ms`), so if all replicas crash within 10 seconds, will I lose all that data? Does it mean that, theoretically, a Cassandra Cluster can lose data?

Comment: Data is not sent to the memtable first! First it's appended to the commitlog and then it's stored in the memtable and then the ack is sent. Check the insert trace: https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/tracing-in-cassandra-1-2

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If a node crashed right before updating the commit log on disk, then yes, you could lose up to ten seconds of data.

If you keep multiple replicas, by using a replication factor higher than 1 or have multiple data centers, then much of the lost data would be on other nodes, and would be recovered on the crashed node when it was repaired.

Also the commit log may be written in less than ten seconds it the write volume is high enough to hit size limits before the ten seconds.

If you want more durability than this (at the cost of higher latency), then you can change the `commitlog_sync` setting from `periodic` to `batch`.  In `batch` mode it uses the `commitlog_sync_batch_window_in_ms` setting to control how often batches of writes are written to disk. In batch mode the writes are not acked until written to disk.

The ten second default for periodic mode is designed for spinning disks, since they are so slow there is a performance hit if you block acks waiting for commit log writes. For this reason if you use `batch` mode, they recommend a dedicated disk for the commit log so that the write head doesn't need to do any seeks to keep the added latency as low as possible.

If you are using SSDs, then you can use more aggressive timing since the latency is greatly reduced compared to a spinning disk.

Comment: As far as i understand commit log is already on the disk, so even if a node crashes in under 10 secs and the restarts, shouldn't it replay everything from commit log and recover the data ?

Comment: @Vinay The data gets written to the disk only after every 10 seconds. Therefore, "you can potentially lose up to that much data if all replicas crash within that window of time." Please check out: https://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/Durability

Comment: "written to disk" should be "fsynced" everywhere. Commit log writes happen before the mutation is completed, but the commitlog itself is not fsynced on every write. The data loss is only expected if the crash is a machine level crash, not a process level one.

Comment: Looks like http://www.mongodb-is-web-scale.com/ applies to Cassandra too

Answer (score 4):

Cassandra's default configuration sets the `commitlog_sync` mode to periodic, causing the commit log to be synced every `commitlog_sync_period_in_ms` milliseconds, so you can potentially lose up to that much data if all replicas crash within that window of time.